# Get commit message in Git hooks

Tags: bash, shell, githooks

I would like to create commit-msg hook to check the commit message with some regex. So I wrote this bash script in the hooks folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

valid_commit_msg_regex="^[0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]{20,150}$"

message="This commit violates the commit message rules. Please rename your commit."

if [[ ! $(cat $1) =~ $valid_commit_msg_regex ]]
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

But when I try to write `git commit -m "9: texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext"` it doesn't work properly and I get the error message from script. 
Does anyone has an idea what's gone wrong?

Comment: what is the error message ? have you searched for something like "shell check if message matches regexp" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

- Double brackets `[[` comes from bash. Change shebang to `#!/bin/bash`
- in `[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]` you have to escape `-` with `\-`